# How to hide navbarMenus with shinyjs?

Tags: r, shiny, hidden, shinyjs

This question delas with the combination of navbarMenus and the shinyjs package. I've build a shiny app and I also added an user-login following this suggestion: https://gist.github.com/withr/9001831.

So I know, which user is logged in. Now I'd like to show and hide both a whole navbarMenu and single tabPanels, depending on which user is logged in. Let's say, there are two users, 'admin' and 'custom', and for 'admin' all navbarMenus and all tabPanels should be shown, while 'custom' only gets  navbarMenu 2 and within this menu only tabPanel 22 to see.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# Define UI
ui <-
fluidPage(
titlePanel("NAVBARPAGE"), # title
br(),
################### NAVBAR  ############################
navbarPage(
"", # title
################### TABS THEMA  #######################
hidden(div(id='m1',
navbarMenu("Menu1",
tabPanel('tab11',plotOutput('tab_11')),
tabPanel('tab12',uiOutput('tab_12'))))),
navbarMenu("Menu2",
tabPanel('tab21',uiOutput('tab_21')),
hidden(div(id='xxx',tabPanel('tab22',uiOutput('tab_22')))))
#######################################################
))

###### SERVER #####
server <- function(input, output,session) {
#Define user
user<-'admin'

observe({
if (user=='admin') {
show('xxx')
show('m1')
}
else {
hide('xxx')
hide(m1)
}
})
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In this minimal example, the tabPanel ('tab22') is hidden, but is does not show up, when I define

```
user<-'custom'
```

Plus, the appearance of the first navbarMenu 'm1' is strange - it is actually not hidden, it is only only empty. 
Does anyone know help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some errors, missing `}` at the end of your `server` function, calling the `hide` funciton with `m1` instead of `"m1"`, and not initialize `shinyjs` with `shinyjs::useShinyjs()`. In addition, you can not use a `div` around `navbarMenu` or `tabPanel`, they will not be rendered. Lastly, it would be very easy for any user to show/hide the content.

A better option is to create the `navbar` according to the user using a `uiOutput` and control what to render using the user name. Below is an example based on your code to show content based on the users.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("userSL", 'Users:', c('admin', 'custom')),
  titlePanel("NAVBARPAGE"), 
  br(),
  uiOutput("navbarPageUI")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$navbarPageUI <- renderUI({
    user <- input$userSL
    if (user == 'admin') {
      navbarPage("", 
        navbarMenu("Menu1",
          tabPanel('tab11',plotOutput('tab_11')),
          tabPanel('tab12',uiOutput('tab_12'))
        ),
        navbarMenu("Menu2",
          tabPanel('tab21',uiOutput('tab_21')),
          tabPanel('tab22',uiOutput('tab_22'))
        )
      )
    } else {
      navbarPage("", 
        navbarMenu("Menu2",
          tabPanel('tab21',uiOutput('tab_21'))
        )
      )
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, Geovany, that helped a lot. One more questions: You mentioned, it would be easy for any user to show any hidden content. Can you explain why. Thanks.

Comment: I ran into this question here while I was browsing around for a similar solution. This answer is a bit crude since it uses `renderUI` to build the ui from within the server - this is very inefficient, and not recommended (for example, menu2 has to be built twice). Instead consider using the following: [https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/issues/43](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/issues/43).